# How do I compare two variables containing strings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want compare two variables, that are strings, but I am getting an error.

```js
<script>
    var to_check=$(this).val();
    var cur_string=$("#0").text();
    var to_chk = "that";
    var cur_str= "that";

    if(to_chk==cur_str){
        alert("both are equal");
        $("#0").attr("class","correct");    
    } else {
        alert("both are not equal");
        $("#0").attr("class","incorrect");
    }
</script>
```

Is something wrong with my if statement?

Comment: This should do the trick, its not where your problem is. Show the code.

Comment: please post more code with how you get to_chk and cur_str ... can't tell from that

Comment: You haven't mentioned what error you are getting..

Comment: This code works in Chrome and FF.

Comment: try to delete any whitespace from begining and end of string and convert to lower case

Comment: its not entering inside if condition always going in else one.

Comment: well it seems to work (I debugged on Chrome Dev Tools), so please provide more info

Comment: Are there any console errors present in FF or Chrome?

Comment: @TommyBs no there is no console error.

Comment: Is there more code on this page you can show us as that should work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`===` is not necessary. You know both values are strings so you dont need to compare types.

```js
function do_check()
{
  var str1 = $("#textbox1").val();
  var str2 = $("#textbox2").val();

  if (str1 == str2)
  {
    $(":text").removeClass("incorrect");
    alert("equal");
  }
  else
  {
    $(":text").addClass("incorrect");
    alert("not equal");
  }
}
```

```css
.incorrect
{
  background: #ff8888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="textbox1" type="text">
<input id="textbox2" type="text">

<button onclick="do_check()">check</button>
```

Comment: I had same issue today and comparison would not work. After spending couple of hours pulling my hair, i figured i was initializing my variable as var x; and comparison did not work. When I changed var x=""; it worked. So I am guessing, it was using object comparison as oppose to string comparison.

Answer (score 6):

instead of using the `==` sign, more safer use the `===` sign when compare, the code that you post is work well

Comment: No, both values in the comparision will be strings.

Comment: how do you achieve this? if(a b)  a = 12345 , b = 123 to be true, because a has all of b elements?

Answer (score 3):

You can use javascript dedicate string compare method **string1.localeCompare(string2)**.
it will five you **-1** if the string not equals, **0** for strings equal and **1** if string1 is sorted after string2.

```
<script>
    var to_check=$(this).val();
    var cur_string=$("#0").text();
    var to_chk = "that";
    var cur_str= "that";
    if(to_chk.localeCompare(cur_str) == 0){
        alert("both are equal");
        $("#0").attr("class","correct");    
    } else {
        alert("both are not equal");
        $("#0").attr("class","incorrect");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this , it works.

```
<script>
var to_check=$(this).val();
var cur_string=$("#0").text();
var to_chk = "that";
var cur_str= "that";
if(to_chk.localeCompare(cur_str) === 0){
    alert("both are equal");
    $("#0").attr("class","correct");    
} else {
    alert("both are not equal");
    $("#0").attr("class","incorrect");
}
```

Comment: Copied 1:1 from Kiran Chenna's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used below function to compare two strings and It is working good.

```
function CompareUserId (first, second)
{

   var regex = new RegExp('^' + first+ '$', 'i');
   if (regex.test(second)) 
   {
        return true;
   }
   else 
   {
        return false;
   }
   return false;
}
```