# String comparison in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, string

```
for(i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
    if((contacts[i].lname.toUpperCase().charAt(0))===(lastName.toUpperCase()))
        window.alert("already exists");
}
```

Am I doing correct? It is not working  even if lastName already exists! Is there any other way to compare Strings in Javascript?

Comment: What is `not working`?

Comment: `.charAt(0)`? are you comparing first character with `lastName`?

Comment: What are the strings?  What does your debugger say?

Comment: You're comparing the first character lname to the entire lastName string. Remove the charAt call.

Comment: You are right. I didn't notice charAt(0). It is working .

Comment: This question already been answered <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737974/how-do-i-compare-two-variables-containing-strings-in-javascript"> here </a>

Answer (score 3):

as pointed out i think it should be

```
for(i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
    if( contacts[i].lname.toUpperCase() === lastName.toUpperCase() )
        window.alert("already exists");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like:

```
for(i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
            if((contacts[i].lname.toUpperCase())===(lastName.toUpperCase()))
                window.alert("Last name already exists");
            else
            contacts.push(person);  
        }
```