# String comparison of variable not working

Tags: jquery

Does anyone have a clue what could be wrong with my JS. I have stared at this for a day and cannot come up with a fix. Any pointers would be great. I am not looking for comments on the code. Solutions only please.

`var obj` returns `0of0` and `11of11`.

**JS**

```
    $('tbody tr td .h5').parents('tr').each(function(){

        var obj = $(this).find('span.meter-description').html().replace(/ /g, "");

        console.log(obj);
        console.log('--');

        if(obj == '0of0'){
            alert('hello');
        }

    });
```

**HTML**

```
<tr class="evenLocation separator-bttm">
    <td class="text-middle"><strong class="h5 text-primary">35061077(<abbr title="Mail Out">M/O</abbr>)</strong></td>
    <td class="text-center"><div class="meter blue"><span style="width: 0%"></span></div><span class="meter-description">0 of 0</span></td>
    <td class="text-center">0</td><td class="text-center">0.0</td>
    <td>None</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `)` on the condition. Assuming that's just a typo in the question only, then please add your HTML.

Comment: sorry pasted the wrong code. The code has been updated and still does not work.

Comment: The html is full of sensitive data.

Comment: Please check if this link helps you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737974/how-do-i-compare-two-variables-containing-strings-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just missing the trimming of extra space around obj!

```js
$('tbody tr td .h5').parents('tr').each(function(){

        var obj = $(this).find('span.meter-description').html().replace(/ /g, "");
        console.log(obj);
        console.log('--');

        if($.trim(obj) == '0of0'){
            alert('hello');
        }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="h5">
            </div>
          </td>
        <td>
          <span class="meter-description">
            0 of 0
            </span>
          </td>
        
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: spaces where? The html is generated from a jsp.

Comment: you need accurate check of obj whether its equal to 0of0?

Comment: I ended up changin == '0of0' to == '0 of 0' and removing .replace(/ /g, ""). Adding $.trim(obj) to the if statement was all I needed. Thanks koded!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
 $('tbody tr td .h5').parents('tr').each(function(__idx, __el){

    var obj = $(__el).find('span.meter-description').html().replace(/ /g, "");        

});
```

Comment: hard to help you without html but your each function always point to the same node - this at least does not... please post html, or at least pseudo html with fake values